# Manipulating prewritten MySQL query - PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following query which returns a list of 8 post ids for wordpress, i want to then take those 8 ids and match them to the id's from the wp_posts table and get * details so i can echo post titles and all that, is there a way i can do that in one query? .. here is what i currently have

```
SELECT postid FROM wp_popularpostsdata WHERE DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 60 DAY) <= day 
AND wp_popularpostsdata.postid NOT IN (
SELECT object_id
FROM wp_term_relationships AS r
    JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS x ON x.term_taxonomy_id = r.term_taxonomy_id
    JOIN wp_terms AS t ON t.term_id = x.term_id
WHERE   x.taxonomy = 'category'
AND t.term_id IN (3,1)) 
GROUP BY postid                                     
ORDER BY pageviews DESC LIMIT 8;
```

Cheeers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried joining the tables?

```
SELECT postid, wp_posts.* FROM wp_popularpostsdata 
LEFT JOIN wp_posts ON wp_posts.id = wp_popularpostsdata.postid 
WHERE 
   DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 60 DAY) <= day AND 
   wp_popularpostsdata.postid NOT IN (
      SELECT object_id
      FROM wp_term_relationships AS r
      JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS x ON x.term_taxonomy_id = r.term_taxonomy_id
      JOIN wp_terms AS t ON t.term_id = x.term_id
      WHERE   
       x.taxonomy = 'category' AND 
       t.term_id IN (3,1)) 
GROUP BY postid                                     
ORDER BY pageviews DESC LIMIT 8;
```

Replace `wp_posts.id` with the key field in wp_posts

Answer (score 0):

Or you could so another subselect to get just the wp_posts data.

```
SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE id IN (
  SELECT postid FROM wp_popularpostsdata 
  WHERE DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 60 DAY) <= day 
  AND wp_popularpostsdata.postid 
  NOT IN (
    SELECT object_id
    FROM wp_term_relationships AS r
        JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS x ON x.term_taxonomy_id = r.term_taxonomy_id
        JOIN wp_terms AS t ON t.term_id = x.term_id
    WHERE   x.taxonomy = 'category'
    AND t.term_id IN (3,1)
      ) 
  GROUP BY postid                                     
  ORDER BY pageviews DESC LIMIT 8;
)
```

Comment: Oh, didn't know that about MySQL.  I mostly work with PostgreSQL which will allow this.  Good to know.

Answer (score 0):

You should put the id's array ( '155', '312', '18','22',... ) in

```
$posts = new WP_Query(array(
    'post__in'  => array( '155', '312', '18','22',.. ) /* YOUR ARRAY */
));
```

It will give you the posts with filters applied. More information for WP_query on http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query

?>